# Smooth Scrolling Child Element of Document without Scrolling Document

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

There's a million answers to the typical smooth scroll.  What's different is that I'm trying to get element2 (with scroll bar) to smooth scroll when clicking on a link in element1.  Maybe this isn't possible. The element scrolls (not slow), and unfortunately the parent window scrolls also.  I'll get to the HTML, jQuery, & CSS...

HTML:

```
<div class="element1">
<a href="#123">Click to See Listing</a>
<a href="#124">Click to See Listing</a>
<a href="#125">Click to See Listing</a>
</div>

<div class="element2 listings">
<div class="listing" id="123">element contents</div>
<div class="listing" id="124">element contents</div>
<div class="listing" id="125">element contents</div>
etc. etc.
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
    jQ=jQuery.noConflict();
    jQ(document).ready(function(){
        jQ("a").on('click', function(event) {
            if (this.hash !== "") {
                event.preventDefault();
                var hash = this.hash;
                jQ('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: jQ(hash).offset().top-100
                }, 800);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've also tried jQ('.listings') instead of jQ('html, body')

CSS:

```
.listings {
width:300px;
height:500px;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$('.listings').animate({
      scrollTop: ($(hash).offset().top + $('.listings').scrollTop())- 20
 }, 800);
```

The problem is when you are including the offset() you also need to include the current scrollvalue of the scrollContainer

Attached a fiddle for ref
https://jsfiddle.net/70b9mry4/

Comment: Your answer seems to work perfectly on the fiddle.  I have a custom Google Map using the Maps API.  And listings to the right of the map in a fixed height container with scroll bar.  This does solve the issue of the entire page scrolling, but smooth scroll is not working. From the console: [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.  Read the documentation and tried implementing, but still no smooth scroll.  I'm happy with what you gave, though, as it solves half my issue.